# CLLocation Manager work only for the application first run

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager, updating, upstart

CLLocation Manager work only for the application first run.
This is my code.

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
{
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: It works only first time? or it doesn't work first time?

Comment: it work the first time when i restart app it does not work

Comment: This code shouldn't work the first time. It should always fail first time and succeed in the later runs. I don't know how its the way around in your case!

Comment: can you please add more code. and show us where you execute those lines?

Comment: can you give me the solution the code you use ?

Comment: I am at work and going home now. I will post you the code in an hour

Comment: i use the code in the the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the probleme was from simulator when you restart the application the location turn to the default location which is none.

So when i restart my app i got the the error didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0.

You should when reopen the application choose a new location from debug -> location, or use a device for test.

Comment: but, this is not the corrent way to ask for permission and start updating location. my comment still hold it will not work first time.

Comment: no it work fo me like that i add message to show when ask for permission in info.plist and use the delegate function to get the location and it work all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try the freeway drive in the location debug for simulator to test your location, when you close the app location go to none.
Change it to freeway drive

Comment: Ok. test it and let me know. Good luck